# Send private message to client using socket io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have a problem to send private message to specific client.
This event "conversation private post" doesn't work, my clients never see this private information.

I don't know what is wrong.

This is my code:

**server.js**

```
io.on('connection', function (socket, username) {
    console.log('New client connected (id=' + socket.id + ').');

    socket.on('subscribe', function(room) {
        console.log('joining room', room);
        socket.join(room);
    });

    socket.on('send message', function(data) {
        console.log('sending room post', data.room);
        socket.to(data.room).emit('conversation private post', {
            message: data.message
        });
    });
});
```

**client.js**

```
  <html>

    <head>
    <title>Getting started with Sockets</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>

    <script>
       var conversation_id  = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 )
       var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
       socket.emit('subscribe', conversation_id);

       socket.emit('send message', {
           room: conversation_id,
           message: "Some message"
       });

       socket.on('conversation private post', function(data) {
          console.log("Private conversation", data)
       });
     </script>

   </head>

   <body>
     <div id="serverMsg">Waiting for the message from server:</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: One solution might be to have different pub-sub channels for each room/user-pair you want to send private messages to. Currently you are broadcasting the message to all the users in the `room` on the `send message` event.

Comment: Have you debugged `send message` on the server side? Is `data.room` coming through as expected?

Answer (score 0):

On the client, emit an object to the server with the following data:

```
{
    to: [the other receiver's username as a string] ,
    from: [the person who sent the message as string] ,
    message: [the message to be sent as string]
}
```

On the server, listen for messages. When a message is received, emit the data to the receiver.

```
"the user you want to send"[data.to].emit('receivedMessage', data)
```